# What Can I do with same generics like this List<? ...>?

Tags: java, generics, collections, type-conversion, covariance

I declares collection so

```
 List<? extends Number> ml = new Vector<Integer>();
```

I try to add element

It is not valid :

```
ml.add(new Integer(1));
```

it is too

```
ml.add(new Object());
```

I very confused. How can I use `ml`?

Comment: Don't use Vector class. It's there for legacy support. Do you need your list to be synchronized at all?

Comment: as you say - will not use Stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lists are not covariant. If you use `? extends Number` then you can only read from the list, you can't write to it. Why not?

```
m1.add(new Object());
```

It should be obvious why this doesn't work. The list is supposed to contain `Number`s and an `Object` is not a `Number`.

```
ml.add(new Integer(1));
```

This one's not so obvious. Imagine that you had a different instantiation of `m1`:

```
List<? extends Number> ml = new Vector<Double>();
ml.add(new Integer(1));
```

Now `m1` is a vector of doubles. Adding an integer to this list would be illegal. The compiler doesn't in general know what the concrete type of `? extends Number` is. To be conservative, it disallows calling the `add` method entirely. You can iterate over the list and read what's in it, and you can delete items from it, but you can't add new items to it.

Or to put it another way, for `List<E>` you can call methods that return `E` but you can't call ones that take `E` as a parameter.

Comment: What the reason to allow this syntax?

Comment: @gstackoverflow To allow programming to the interface. For example, I can have a method that takes in a List<? extends Number>, and it sums up all the numbers. It's gonna work with all Lists of numbers.

Comment: Why do just **List<Number>** bad at this situation?

Comment: Right, this syntax is probably most useful for defining the type of a method parameter, allowing the method to iterate and read from the incoming list.

Comment: @gstackoverflow Because List<Integer> is not a List<Number>. Regular Java inheritance does not apply to collections. List<Number> is a type of its own.

Comment: Yes, it can. But `List<Number> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();` will fail to compile. `Integer` is a subclass of `Number`, but `List<Integer>` is not a subclass of `List<Number>`. That's why `List<? extends Number> l = listOfNumbersOrIntegersOrDoubles()` is useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call methods parameterized with an upper-bounded wildcard. No type can satisfy that wildcard except the capture of the wildcard itself.

```
list.add(E e)
```

ends up as

```
list.add(<capture-of ? extends Number> e)
```

There's no capture happening on the type of your variable `ml`.

Comment: What the term "capture" ?

Comment: It's "wildcard capture", the type transformation which compiler does for wildcarded types to transform them into a more specific type depending on context.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are declaring ml as a generic List. Since you are using a wildcard, you can only know that the actual type of the contained objects might be a Number or one of it's subtype. But the JVM doesn't really know what exactly this type is. Thus, this declaration makes ml to be a  read-only List. That's why you cannot add any element in it, just get and read them. 
Change it to: List